# I want to get hour ranges of a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series

I want to demonstrate the hour ranges of a dataframe which has index column as date.

For example, I have as the following data:

```
Date                   col1 
2019-10-10 00:00:00    person1
2019-10-10 01:00:00    person1
2019-10-10 02:00:00    person1
2019-10-10 03:00:00    person2
2019-10-10 04:00:00    person2
2019-10-10 05:00:00    person2
2019-10-10 06:00:00    person2
2019-10-10 07:00:00    person2
2019-10-10 08:00:00    person3
2019-10-10 09:00:00    person3
2019-10-10 10:00:00    person3
2019-10-10 11:00:00    person3
2019-10-10 12:00:00    person3
```

I want to this data like this:

```
Hour               col2
00:00 - 02:00      person1
03:00 - 07:00      person2
08:00 - 12:00      person3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`Series.dt.time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

```
new_df=df.groupby('col1')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.dt.time.iloc[0].strftime("%H:%M")+ '-'+x.dt.time.iloc[len(x)-1].strftime("%H:%M")).rename('Hour').reset_index()
print(new_df)
```

---

```
      col1         Hour
0  person1  00:00-02:00
1  person2  03:00-07:00
2  person3  08:00-12:00
```